# Почему лагает redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux

в рендеринге табличных данных используется прелоадер

```
      {self.props.items.length === 0 ?
        <div>
          {!self.state.isLoading ?
            <div className="block-not-found">Not found</div> :
            <div className="block-loading"><img .../></div>
          }
        </div>
        :
        <div>
          <table>...
```

обновление `items` и `isLoading` запускается синхронно:

```
fetch(...)
.then(...) {
...

    dispatch({ type: 'FETCH_ITEMS_SUCCESS', data: items });
    self.state.isLoading = false;
}
```

редюсер прост до неприличия:

```
export default function items(state = initialState, action) {
  if (action.type === 'FETCH_ITEMS_SUCCESS') {
    return action.data;
  }
  return state;
}
```

но при рендеринге после прелоадера, но до отрисовки таблицы возникает надпись `Not found`

вот лог состояний из рендера:

> isLoading: true length: 0
>
> isLoading: false length: 0
>
> isLoading: false length: 50

почему `items` и `isLoading` обновляются не синхронно?

Comment: redux всё выполнил синхронно, но реакт не гарантирует, что props и state изменятся синхронно. К тому же изменять так state нельзя, нужно использовать метод `setState`. А в данном случае вообще не нужен state и флаг isLoading должен быть redux

Comment: `isLoading должен быть redux` - это как? дайте ссылку

Comment: Пример в документации redux http://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/ExampleRedditAPI.html `isFetching` (ваш `isLoading`) это часть стора

Comment: @AlexeyTen оформите Ваш комментарий как ответ

Answer (score 1):

Пример в [документации redux](https://redux.js.org/advanced/example-reddit-api), где `isFetching` (ваш `isLoading`) это часть стора

Ответ [@Alexey Ten](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/190728/alexey-ten)